# Conflict between internal and homebrew installed apache

Tags: macos, apache

Helo everyone,  my lap is undergoing some conflict in case of internal apache (mac provide built in apache server) and home brew installed apache.. So that I cant access my localhost. Can anyone fix this?

Which -a httpd (terminal command) result two output ,

/usr/local/bin/httpd (home brew installed apache

/usr/sbin/httpd (default apache)

Whereis httpd (terminal command) results 
/usr/sbin/httpd (it seems default apache)

But when I check httpd -V in terminal  it gives path of homebrew intalled apache

I don't know which server is running internal or homebrew installed apache. I want to uninstall this homebrew installed apache and use default apache...

Comment: Just remove the **homebrew** one with `brew rm apache2` and restart your machine.

Comment: @MarkSetchell i have run that.. and uninstall the homebrew installed apache. But still httpd -V shows "/usr/local/bin/httpd: No such file or directory" or if you can use teamviwer you can fix this error

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't work like that! Try running `type httpd` to see if you have made an alias or a function.

Comment: when i restart the machine httpd -V shows correct.. Thanks

Comment: @MarkSetchell localhost says refuses to connect. dont know why. /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file may be corrupted.

Comment: apachectl configtest doesn't shows any error.But still localhost refuses to connect